# scroll in Microsoft USB mouse is not working properly

Tags: mouse, scrolling

I found wonder that up to Ubuntu 11.10, my Microsoft USB mouse scroll function worked properly, but after updating to 12.04 LTS, it just jumping like unevenly and jumpy.

I replaced the  Microsoft USB mouse with ball it works okay.
Please help to rectify.

Answer (score -2):

It's a know bug which happen with a lot of Microsoft mice, the only solution I've found is to unplug it and plug it back. Then it's working properly until the next reboot.

Comment: Please, add a link with the bug.

Comment: This is a good answer on solving it so it shouldn't get a -1.